# How to use aws cli binary in aws lambda cutom RunTime (Shell)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Unable to run AWS CLI in Lambda custom run time, getting an error:

> aws command not found

```
python3 -m venv lambdaVirtualEnv 
source activate lambdaVirtualEnv
pip3 install awscli
copied the aws binary and contents under the site-packages to lambdaLayerDir 
Created a lambda layer using lambdaLayerDir.zip file.
```

```
function handler () 
{
    PATH=${PATH}:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
    echo $PATH
    EVENT_DATA=$1
    RESPONSE="{\"statusCode\": 200, \"body\": \"Hello from Lambda!\"}"
    echo $RESPONSE
    aws
}
```

Output:

```
> * Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
/var/task/hello.sh: line 9: aws: command not found
END RequestId: b2225b95-c53c-4271-a664-873dc19528b4
REPORT RequestId: b2225b95-c53c-4271-a664-873dc19528b4  Init Duration: 33.70 ms Duration: 431.44 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 45 MB  
RequestId: b2225b95-c53c-4271-a664-873dc19528b4 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 127
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: The error says `aws: command not found`. It would appear that either the AWS CLI is not correctly installed, or the script you are running is not using the virtual environment you have setup. (You do not show how `hello.sh` is being triggered.)

Comment: tried to use the hello.sh and other modules into the same zip and used as zip in the function code it. All the modules, bootstrap and hello.sh goes to the same directory /var/task and it works fine. 
problem is, when the modules are exported and given as layer, it errors out.

how to refer the binary in the layers. layered.zip would go to which path ? /tmp ?